# How to do a python relative import from a sibling package

Tags: python, import, relative-import

With this directory structure (this is a toy example, for brevity):

[image]

I have these simple modules:

[image: Main module]

[image: One.py]

[image: Two.py]

When I try to run m.py, I get an error like

> File "...\test\p2\two.py", line 1, in 
> from ..p1 import one ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

What is the correct way to (relative) import module one into module two, when module one is in a package (p1) at the same level in the directory hierarchy as the package (p2) containing module two?  I tried "from ..p1" since p1 is at the same dir level as p2, so "up 2 levels, down 1" fit my brain at first. I also tried "from .p1" and "from test.p1" but no joy.

Comment: Change to `from .p1`. `..` goes outside `test`

Comment: Please see the top-voted answer on the duplicate, not the accepted answer.

Comment: @bdbd `from .p1` doesn't work since p1 is not under p2, it's in the same directory as p2

Comment: Strange.. `from .p1` means *from the same directory where i am, use p1*. `..`goes up two levels